# How to create a hidden VeraCrypt encrypted volume with zuluCrypt-cli

Tags: encryption, veracrypt

To create a normal VeraCrypt encrypted volume with zuluCrypt-cli:

```
$ sudo zuluCrypt-cli -c -d [volume_to_encrypt] -z vfat -t vcrypt -g "/dev/urandom.aes:twofish:serpent.xts-plain64.256.sha512"
```

But how I can create a hidden VeraCrypt encrypted volume? (zuluCrypt GUI is capable to create it)